# How to make a Select Option for Birth Date in JADE html form

Tags: html, forms, pug

I am using JADE and I need to make a for with birth date fields. I thinking make this with select option but I want to know what is the best practice for this form:

```
label Fecha de Nacimiento:
    select
        option(value=00) Día 
        option(value=01) 01
        option(value=01) 02
        option(value=01) 03
        option(value=01) 04
        option(value=01) 05
        option(value=01) 06
    select
        option(value=00) Mes 
        option(value=Ene) Enero
        option(value=Feb) Febrero
        option(value=Mar) Marzo
        option(value=Abr) Abril
        option(value=May) Mayo
        option(value=Jun) Junio
    Select
        option(value=00) Año 
        option(value=1998) 1998
        option(value=1997) 1997
        option(value=1996) 1996
        option(value=1995) 1995
        option(value=1994) 1994
        option(value=1993) 1993
```

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

Comment: Excelent! Thank you for your response! regards!

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped.